# Removing user tags in django

Tags: django

I have been using taggit feature in django for hobbies . Each user can add his hobbies in his profile and tags will be created like tennis or watching movies.

I have created a cloud to show him the tags that he has already added :

```
<div class="rounded-tag-container">
      {% tag_edit person_id=person.id %}
</div>
```

this is also html for this cloud:

```
    {% for tag in tags %}
        <span class="rounded-tag">
            <a href="#" style="color:blue;">
                {{ tag.name }}
            </a>
        <span class="close-button" onclick="removeTag(this, '{{ tag.name }}')">  <strong>×</strong></span>
        </span>
    {% endfor %}

<script>

function removeTag(element, tag_name) {
    element.parentNode.remove();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/hobbies/' + person_id + '/',
        data: { tag_name: tag_name, csrfmiddlewaretoken: csrftoken },
        success: function(response) {
            console.log(response);
        },
        error: function(error) {
            console.error('Error deleting tag:', error);
        }
    });
}
```

also In my hobbies view I defined tag_name:

```
        tag_name = request.POST.get('tag_name')


        if tag_name :
        try:
            person.tags.remove( tag_name)
            messages.success(request, 'Tag deleted successfully')
        except Tag.DoesNotExist:
            messages.error(request, 'Tag not found')
        else:
            messages.error(request, 'Tag name not provided')
```

when the user clicks on the close button of each tags,it will be removed from the client side  and then clicks on submit,it must remove the tag in post request from db, but it does not remove it from database!